# How would I add a homepage link to the navigation of a new WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am designing a WordPress theme and am currently building the nav for my homepage.
The code number 1 allows me to create pages using the custom menu penal. I am using code number 2 to create a link to the current page which it index so bloginfo('url'); would give me the URL to the site which would be the home page, at least that is my under standing. I could use a custom link to add a link to the menu and link to the home page but I would like the theme to have a link to the home page that is native or is in the menu at the on set. Any thoughts on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!--code number 1-->
<ul id="menu">
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
</ul>

<!--code number 2-->
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is exactly. "code number 2" does what you want - it genrates a menu like this: HOME | TOP_LEVEL_PAGE1 | TOP_LEVEL_PAGE2 | ETC - However, you're writing "code number 1 allows me to create pages using the custom menu panel". That is not true. `wp_list_pages` lists pages as they are. You can change order with the `sort_column` parameter, but that's it. If you want to use the "Menus" option in wp-admin, you have to use `wp_nav_menu` instead.

Comment: You should follow the WP-Documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu and in your theme's functions.php add the following code: `/**
 * Get our wp_nav_menu() fallback, wp_page_menu(), to show a home link.
 *
 * To override this in a child theme, remove the filter and optionally add
 * your own function tied to the wp_page_menu_args filter hook.
 *
 */
function my_page_menu_args( $args ) {
 $args['show_home'] = true;
 return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'my_page_menu_args' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the relatively new Wordpress Menu feature instead.

Add the following [register_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) function to your functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'template_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'template_setup' ) ):

function template_setup() {
    // register nave menu
    register_nav_menu('primary','Main Menu');
}
endif;
```

If you already have a function that fires on 'template_setup', the just add the following line to that function:

```
register_nav_menu('primary','Main Menu');
```

Then in your header.php (or where ever you want the menu to appear) add the call to [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main Menu','container' => false )); ?>
```

Then log in to your Wordpress Admin area, with a username that has Admin privileges. Goto Appearance > Menus (this is a new page that will be accessible, after registering the menu in your functions.php file).

Create a new menu, call it what you like, and assign it to the theme location, in this case 'Main Menu'. Here you can now build your menu from any pages, posts, categories etc. that are in your wordpress installation. Also included is a handy link to 'Home'. For more information on the interface see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen).

The interface is lovely as well, nice drag and drop and the additional benefit of your menu remaining the same, even when you add new pages.

/

Also if you want users who aren't Admin's, but who are 'Editors' to be able to edit the menu, add the following to your functions.php file.

```
// editor role - add appearance menu
$role_object = get_role( 'editor' );
// add $cap capability to this role object
$role_object->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
```

Comment: "Also included is a handy link to 'Home'" ok I find it under the view all tab in the menu admin, when I choose to add all it creates a custom menu item but how would I make this item a standard item with the theme. In the other words the user as 'Home' automatically at the onset of creating the menu and would add all other page except the Home page which would already be in the menu. Trying to cut down on what users would have to do so that the theme is simple to use.

Comment: The 'Home' page is dictated by what you have set in your 'Settings > Reading' section. i.e. If you have your homepage set to a page, or set to be your blog listing. 

I'm a bit confused by what you are trying to achieve. Once the menu is built, it is built, no?

Comment: I would like to have the home button to be place in the menu before the menu is built given that the user will always need a home button. I would like it to be there as a default setting. Is that ill-advised?